# Bash "command not found" error

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to edit my .bashrc file with a custom function to launch xwin. I want it to be able to open in multiple windows, so I decided to make a function that accepts 1 parameter: the display number. Here is my code:

```
function test(){
    a=$(($1-0))
    "xinit -- :$a -multiwindow -clipboard &"
}
```

The reason why I created a variable "a" to hold the input is because I suspected that the input was being read in as a string and not a number. I was hoping that taking the step where I subtract the input by 0 would convert the string into an integer, but I'm not actually sure if it will or not. Now, when I call

```
test 0
```

I am given the error

```
-bash: xinit -- :0 -multiwindow -clipboard &: command not found
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `xinit -- ":$a" -multiwindow -clipboard &`

Comment: If you quote it, bash will search for an executable named [[the whole thing with spaces and stuff]].

Comment: `a` is still a string; `bash` doesn't have any other type. What it *does* do, however, is interpret strings as numbers when appropriate (such as inside `$((...))`). Just use `$1` where you would use `$a`.

Answer (score 6):

Because the entire quoted command is acting as the command itself:

```
$ "ls"
a b c
$ "ls -1"
-bash: ls -1: command not found
```

Get rid of the double quotation marks surrounding your `xinit`:

```
xinit -- ":$a" -multiwindow -clipboard &
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the double-quotes bishop pointed out, there are several other problems with this function:

- `test` is a standard, and very important, command. *Do not redefine it*! If you do, you risk having some script (or sourced file, or whatever) run:

  ```
  if test $num -eq 5; then ...
  ```

  Which will fire off `xinit` on some random window number, then continue the script as if $num was equal to 5 (whether or not it actually is). This way lies madness.
- As chepner pointed out in a comment, bash doesn't really have an integer type. To it, an integer is just a string that happens to contain only digits (and maybe a "-" at the front), so converting to integer is a non-opertation. But what you might want to do is check whether the parameter got left off. You can either check whether `$1` is empty (e.g. `if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then echo "Usage: ..." >&2` etc), or supply a default value with e.g. `${1:-0}` (in this case, "0" is used as the default).
- Finally, don't use the `function` keyword. bash tolerates it, but it's nonstandard and doesn't do anything useful.

So, here's what I get as the cleaned-up version of the function:

```
launchxwin() {
    xinit -- ":${1:-0}" -multiwindow -clipboard &
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That happens because bash interprets everything inside quotes as a String. A command is an array of strings which the first element is a binary file or a internal shell command. Subsequent strings in the array are taken as argument.

When you type:

```
"xinit -- :$a -multiwindow -clipboard &"
```

the shell thinks that everything you wrote is a command. Depending on the command/program you ran all the rest of the arguments can be a single string. But mostly you use quotes only if you are passing a argument that has spaces inside like:

```
mkdir "My Documents"
```

That creates a single directory named My Documents. Also, you could escape spaces like this.

```
mkdir My\ Documents
```

But remember, "$" is a special character like "\". It gets interpreted by the shell as a variable. "$a" will be substituted by its value before executing. If you use a simple quote ('$a') it will not be interpreted by the shell.

Also, "&" is a special character that executes the command in background. You should probably pass it outside the quotes also.