# "Command not found" when adb is run from a function but not otherwise

Tags: macos, shell, unix, zsh

Got the function inside my ~/.zshrc file, which prints **command not found: adb**

```
install_apk_on_device() {
  set -x
  local device=${1}
  local path=${2}

  if [[ -z "${device}" ]]; then
    echo "The device is empty"
  elif [[ -z "${path}" ]]; then 
    echo "The path is empty"
  else 
    adb -s "$device" install -r "$path"
  fi
}

output: 

+install_apk_on_device:3> local device=emulator-5554
+install_apk_on_device:4> local path=MY_APK_PATH
+install_apk_on_device:6> [[ -z emulator-5554 ]]
+install_apk_on_device:8> [[ -z MY_APK_PATH ]]
+install_apk_on_device:11> adb -s emulator-5554 install -r MY_APK_PATH
install_apk_on_device:11: command not found: adb
```

However, if you run this **adb** command directly with the same arguments, like `adb -s 52036d8b50671495 install -r .//androidApp/build/outputs/apk/debug/androidApp-debug.apk`, the apk will be installed

Also, if I take the **adb** command out of the else-branch right to the begging of the function, it works as expected

```
install_apk_on_device() {
  adb -s "$1" install -r "$2"
  local device=${1}
  local path=${2}

  if [[ -z "${device}" ]]; then
    echo "The device is empty"
  elif [[ -z "${path}" ]]; then 
    echo "The path is empty"
  fi
}
```

These are my PATHS:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
export HOME=/Users/ruanvd5
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_275/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Programming/elixirSourceCode/elixir/bin
export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$HOME/.gradle
```

Also, this is my `declare -p PATH`

```
export -T PATH path=( 
/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/munki /Library/Apple/usr/bin 
/Users/ruanvd5/Library/Android/sdk/emulator 
/Users/ruanvd5/Library/Android/sdk/tools 
/Users/ruanvd5/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin 
/Users/ruanvd5/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools 
/Users/ruanvd5/Programming/elixirSourceCode/elixir/bin 
)
```

Confused what I wrote wrong :-)

Comment: Putting `"adb -s ${device} install -r ${path}"` all in quotes won't work on the command line either. It works when you run it as `adb -s "$device" install -r "$path"`, but the quotes go around individual arguments (to stop them from being split into multiple arguments themselves), not the whole command (which _needs_ to be split into multiple arguments).

Comment: (Note that `${device}` and `$device` have no advantage over each other in this context; whereas there's an unambiguous increase in correctness when making it `"${device}"` or `"$device"` -- the double quotes suppress string-splitting and globing; the curly brackets only do anything when you're parameterizing your expansion, or concatenating into a string with adjoining characters that might otherwise be valid as part of a variable name).

Comment: Tried to run the function without quotes like: adb -s "$device" install -r "$path". Then terminal says `command not found: adb`, however there are paths in my ~/.zshrc. So it still does not work :-(

Comment: what makes me more confused is that this function `reconnect() { adb kill-server && adb start-server }` works perfect 

Comment: Why is that confusing? `reconnect() { adb kill-server && adb start-server; }` is _expected_ to be perfect. As for why `adb -s "$device" install -r "$path"` doesn't work, we'd need to inspect your `PATH` in both the working case and the broken case to know what's different between them.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!! Updated the question 

Comment: Please put the command `declare -p PATH` in the script, so we see what it actually contains at runtime, and edit the values from both a working instance of your script and a failing one. The dotfiles tell us what you expect your PATH to be, but don't tell us if it's somehow different from that.

Comment: And if you took the quotes out of your script and are still having the problem, edit them out of the question too. Right now, the code in the question still has the problem discussed in the linked duplicate, making that duplicate still appropriate. (Editing a question in a way that changes what answers apply is frowned on once you have a good answer that addresses a question as it was originally asked, but if you just have comments and, as in this case, an answer that doesn't successfully solve the original problem, you're fine to edit instead of asking a new question).

Comment: I'd also suggest adding `set -x` to the top of your script to ask the shell to log the commands it's running with how it interprets them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Updated the question. What I found is that writing code that way works perfectly

```
install_apk_on_device() {
  set -x
  adb -s "$1" install -r "$2"
  local device="$1"
  local path="$2"

  if [[ -z "${device}" ]]; then
    echo "The device is empty"
  elif [[ -z "${path}" ]]; then 
    echo "The path is empty"
  fi
}
```
However, calling inside the **else**-branch fails the command to run

Comment: Could you show that above code, and that `set -x` emits, showing how it fails to reach the `else` path, [edit]ed into the question? (Because comments silently delete newlines and runs of whitespace, they're quite unsuitable for code).

Comment: Thanks -- that's exactly what I needed. Mea culpa about not recognizing the problem sooner -- I mostly stay far away from zsh as much as possible.

Comment: BTW, though you tagged this both bash and zsh, your edited code would be fine in bash; it's strictly a zsh problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike bash (and other POSIX-compliant shells; this is a place where zsh breaks the specification, as [the standard specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) that only all-caps names in the namespace used for environment variables -- which is *also* the namespace used for regular shell variables -- should be meaningful to POSIX-specified tools), the name `path` is meaningful to zsh even in lowercase. Change your variable name.

That is to say, instead of `local path=${2}` (which, in zsh, changes the active `PATH` as a side effect), make it `local apk_path=$2`.

```
install_apk_on_device() {
  local device apk_path
  device=$1; apk_path=$2

  [[ -z $device ]] && { echo "The device is empty" >&2; return 1; }
  [[ -z $apk_path ]] && { echo "The path is empty" >&2; return 1; }

  adb -s "$device" install -r "$apk_path"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try quoting the assignments

```
  local device="${1}"
  local path="${2}"
```

Comment: If there weren't `local`s on the commands, this would be unambiguously unnecessary (assignments suppress glob expansion and string-splitting, making quotes optional). Even as it is, though, it isn't [the problem responsible for the OP's "command not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991584/zsh-bash-no-such-file-or-directory#comment114900975_64991584), which is discussed in [the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745607). And on that point -- see the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).